# Why does this redirect fail?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cpanel, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect **www.example.com** to **example.com**.
I've used cPanel to config my .htaccess file and added these lines to the end of the file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

However, www.example.com does not redirect to example.com.

What is wrong?

Comment: try to remove the [OR] flag. It should be used with multiple conditions only.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this..

Keep this one rule for all the sub-domains:

```html
# rule for forcing www on main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# rule for removing www on sub domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Let me to know if its works.

Thanks

Comment: I should thank for your answer, however I could find the reason. My DNS servers where located out of my hosting service provider. So at the first point, problem was due to DNS errors and after defining DNS for www. domain problem resolved :)